# how to compare two dataframes to infer third dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, grouping

```
df_base = 
  time_id  object_id  gt_class  hp_class   
0   1      a          CAR       ""         
1   1      b          CAR       ""         
2   2      c          PERSON    PERSON     
3   2      d          PERSON    PERSON     
4   2      e          CAR       ""         

df_feature = 
  time_id   object_id   gt_class    hp_class     
0   1        a          CAR         CAR         
1   1        b          CAR         CAR        
2   2        c         PERSON       ""         
3   2        d         PERSON       ""         
4   2        e          CAR         ""
```

each dataframe represents a `object_id` at time `time_id` with class of `gt_class`(groundtruth class), the corresponding hypothesis class as `hp_class`.
If the groundtruth is missed, the corresponding `hp_class=""`.

I need to compare `df_base` and `df_feature` based on `time_id`. and coming up with the following dataframe

```
compare_df = 
time_id  gt_class num_missed_base num_missed_feature
1        "CAR"    2               0
1        "PERSON" 0               0
2        "PERSON" 0               2
2        "CAR"    1               1
```

For instance in the above example at `time_id == 1`, and `gt_class=="CAR"` there are two missed objects in `base_df` but 0 missed for `feature_df`.

But I don't know how to do that. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do `df_base` and `df_feature` only differ on the `hp_class` column?

Comment: Good question.
No. it is important to find common (time_id, object_id) between base and feature and then find miss detection

Comment: but in `compare_df` there's no sign of `object_id` as if the grouping is based on `time_id` and `gt_class`

Comment: you are right. I meant it should be based on the common pair of (time_id, gt_class)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data:

```
df_base = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'time_id':[1,1,2,2,2], 'object_id':['a','b','c','d','e'], 'gt_class':['CAR', 'CAR', 'PERSON', 'PERSON', 'CAR'], 
            'hp_class':['','','PERSON','PERSON','']})
df_feature = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'time_id':[1,1,2,2,2], 'object_id':['a','b','c','d','e'], 'gt_class':['CAR', 'CAR', 'PERSON', 'PERSON', 'CAR'], 
            'hp_class':['CAR','CAR','','','']})
```

Adding a `flag` column where 1s indicate the missing data:

```
df_feature['flag'] = df_feature.hp_class.apply(lambda x: 1 if x=='' else 0)
df_base['flag'] = df_base.hp_class.apply(lambda x: 1 if x=='' else 0)
```

Grouping based on `time_id` and `gt_class` and summing the missing values:

```
df1 = df_base.groupby(['time_id', 'gt_class'])['flag'].agg(num_missed_base='sum')
df2 = df_feature.groupby(['time_id', 'gt_class'])['flag'].agg(num_missed_feature='sum')
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis = 1, levels=0)
print(df)
                  num_missed_base  num_missed_feature
time_id gt_class                                     
1       CAR                     2                   0
2       CAR                     1                   1
        PERSON                  0                   2
```

Answer (score 0):

### Update pandas 1.1.0 [`pd.DataFrame.compare`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.compare.html#pandas.DataFrame.compare) method

```
df_comp = df_base.compare(df_feature, keep_shape=True, keep_equal=True)
df_out = (df_comp['hp_class']=='').groupby([df_base['time_id'], df_base['gt_class']])\
   .sum().rename(columns={'self':'num_missing_base', 'other':'num_missing_feature'})
print(df_out)
```

Output:

```
                  num_missing_base  num_missing_feature
time_id gt_class                                       
1       CAR                      2                    0
2       CAR                      1                    1
        PERSON                   0                    2
```